# Docker inter-container communication painfully slow (Mac OS X)

Tags: docker

I've got an AngularJS application running on nginx in container1.  When it hits "/api" it gets proxied over to Docker container2 (a PHP API running on Apache).  The PHP API accesses my database that is running locally on Mac OS X.  Docker containers are Ubuntu.

Communication between containers is very slow.  Any idea why?

```
boot2docker start
docker run -d -h docker --name container2 -v ~/container2dir/:/var/www -p 5000:80 seanbollin/image2
docker run -d -h docker --link name:api -v ~/somefolder/:/var/www/anotherfolder/ -p 5001:80 seanbollin/image1
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the size of the mounted directory from "File Sharing" section.
I had a 50GB around folder shared having all my projects. 
I shared the parent folder just to save some time, but it caused the slowness in http responses.

Share only required folder, and use the .dockerignore for any folder that you don't want to mount, ex. "venv" etc.