# Devlibox (Docker) extremly slow on Mac

Tags: php, macos, symfony, docker, docker-compose

I started to use [Devilbox](http://devilbox.org/) on Mac instead of [Valet Plus](https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus). Devilbox is great but it is extremly slow. I found [Performance issues on Docker for Mac](https://devilbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/support/troubleshooting.html#performance-issues-on-docker-for-mac) in documentation, so I added `MOUNT_OPTIONS=,cached` to `.env` file. Result is better performance, but still too slow (30 seconds to load page in Symfony). Devilbox as such runs fast but projects with cache folder nope.

[image]

This is my current Docker setting (I enabled maximum of sources):

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [docker-sync](http://docker-sync.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I tried [docker-sync](http://docker-sync.io/) and I did not realize any speed up. I decided to install [Valet plus](https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus) as I need to have multiple PHP version (easily switchable), MailHog, Xdebug, SSL on local domains, DnsMasq etc. All of this comes out of the box in Valet plus. I thought it would be much better to develop in Docker but [Symfony](http://symfony.com) uses really a lot of cached files on disk so this was really unusable (as page load was between 30 to 60 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

That might be related this answer which I've answered last week.

[Docker in MacOs is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55951014/docker-in-macos-is-very-slow/55953023#55953023)

Because of Mac OS Docker client doesn't equal real Docker performance on Linux.