# Docker not reflecting changes real-time (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, macos, docker, devops

I have Docker desktop (`2.3.0.4`) for Mac (`Catalina 10.15.6`).

What started happening recently is that my changes aren't reflected in real-time when looking from browser perspective.

I have a Laravel app. When I am connected to the app container and when I do the change in my IDE, I notice the file being changed instantly within container as well, so the mapping part works well, however the browser sync happens in about a minute or so (sometimes faster, sometimes slower) which is really frustrating.

For example this part of the code will dump the string within a browser:

```
public function index()
{
    dd('I am here');
}
```

However changing to

```
public function index()
{
    dd('I am there');
}
```

will require me to wait and wait... PHPStorm has auto-save feature enabled, but I do a CTRL-s just to be sure.

My Docker configuration has 6 cores available with 8GB RAM, having only 5 containers up and running (and we are talking minimal workload there).

I thought it might be due to some caching, but flushing cache didn't work, disabling service workers didn't work and incognito mode didn't work. I always have the delay.

Also, to be sure it's not about the framework, I tried doing `artisan optimize:clear` frantically, but to no avail.

What can I do to improve the response time? This is a debugging nightmare.

Comment: I have the same issue, I downgraded and installed docker desktop 3.1.0 and don't have the issue anymore. But now i cannot upgrade to latest version, but this temporarily solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on macOS. Have a look at the following links to see what can be done:

- [Docker in MacOs is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55951014/docker-in-macos-is-very-slow)
- https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/77
- https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync
- https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#performance-issues-solutions-and-roadmap
- https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/

Answer (score -2):

I think that is related to the browser cache
If you are using chrome go to the Inspect tab and go to the network and check the **"Disable cache"** I think it will fix your problem

Comment: Well I did manually flush the cache, and try it out incognito, so I don't think it is a browser cache issue. More even, when I avoid Docker and use a local server, it functions just fine