# Very slow queries between server and database in docker

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to setup some integrations tests with docker compose. I'm using docker compose to spin up a postgres database and a nodejs server. I'm then using jest to run http requests against the server.

For some reasons that I can't explain all SQL queries (even the simplest one) are extremely slow (+ 1s).

It sounds like a communication problem between the two containers, but I can't spot it. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file. The server is just a simple express app

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:12
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U test_user -d test_database
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 0s
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: database
      NODE_ENV: test
    init: true
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080/healthcheck"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 0s
```

**EDIT**
I'm using

```
Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61
macOs BigSur 11.1 (20C69)
```

Comment: 1. Can you make a test for different versions of postgresql? E.g. try postgres:13  or postgres:11 just for test. 2. You mention node.js: which version it is? We had problems with 14  + postgresql. Can you try with 12?  3. Queries are slow only for queries from node.js or from everywhere?

Comment: @AlexYu I found the issue and it was not in docker but in the postgres client. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 9):

Try using Volume instead of Bind Mount for the data folder by changing this:

```
- ./db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

To this:

```
- db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

And adding this section to the end of the compose file:

```
volumes: 
    db-data:
```

You can read more about bind mounts vs volumes [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Comment: (If this is in fact the issue – and it likely may be – see also [Docker in MacOs is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55951014/docker-in-macos-is-very-slow) for other workarounds.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that does not solve my issue. I also tried to add `:delegated` as pointed in the link but it does not work either

Comment: This made a lot of difference for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Indeed, this workaround worked wonder with my SQL Server Docker database. I was using bind mounts which are much less performant in Windows/Mac os (don't know about Linux)  "Volumes on Docker Desktop have much higher performance than bind mounts from Mac and Windows hosts."  Speed is much faster now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found it. The issue is not in docker, but in the compiler. I'm using [ncc](https://github.com/vercel/ncc) and it breaks my postgres client.

I opened an issue in their repo with a minimal reproducible example

https://github.com/vercel/ncc/issues/646

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Hm. Interesting. We had problems with combination of plain `pg` + node 12 (but we don't use ncc). Actually as  `slonik` is built upon `pg` so it's possible that even combination `ncc`+`pg` will display the same problem