# PHP/Symfony is very slow in Docker setup

Tags: php, docker, apache, docker-compose, php-7

## Setup

I have a Symfony 4.4 application. For local development, this is hosted with 3 docker containers. Their base images are:

- mysite: `php:7.1-fpm`
- mysite_apache: `debian:buster`
- mysite_mysql: `mysql:8.0.25`.

## Problem

The main dashboard makes a total of 97 HTTP requests and takes 25s to load using this Docker setup.

When hosting the local environment directly on macOS using the PHP and Apache that come with the OS, it takes 3.5s to load -- 14% of the time -- even when using the same versions of PHP and Apache.

Requests to static resources (js, css, images) are snappy. The API calls, which go to the PHP container (and Symfony), are the problem. They can take upwards of 5s to resolve.

---

## Details

The Apache and php-fpm containers share a volume for the website code. Apache delegates PHP execution to the PHP container via a `FilesMatch .php` in its vhost.

**UPDATE:** I have tried hosting the website directly in the php container using `symfony serve`. It's just as slow, meaning that the issue is probably with the php container's setup, not apache.

### docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    apache:
        build: ./apache
        container_name: mysite_apache
        restart: always
        extra_hosts:
            - "mysite.local:127.0.0.1"
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - ./apache/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled:delegated
            - ./apache/conf:/etc/apache2/conf-enabled:delegated
            # Sites
            - ./mysite:/home/wwwroot/mysite:delegated

    php:
        build: ./php
        container_name: mysite
        volumes:
            - ./mysite:/home/wwwroot/mysite:delegated
            - $HOME/.ssh:/root/.ssh:cached
            - $HOME/.composer/:/root/.composer:cached
        ports:
            - 9001:9001
            - 8000:8000


    mysql:
        # redacted, this probably isn't important
```

### mysite.conf

This is the vhost config for apache

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Define server_name  mysite.local
    Define basedocroot  /home/wwwroot/mysite
    Define docrootweb   ${basedocroot}/public
    Define logdir       /var/log/apache2

    <FilesMatch .php$>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://mysite:9001"
    </FilesMatch>

    ServerName ${server_name}
    ServerAlias www.${server_name}

    DocumentRoot ${docrootweb}
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV dev

    <Directory ${docrootweb}>
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </Directory>

    <Directory ${basedocroot}/vpn/swagger>
        DirectoryIndex index.html
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/server.key

    Undefine server_name
    Undefine basedocroot
    Undefine docrootweb
    Undefine logdir

</VirtualHost>

# HTTP -> HTTPS REDIRECT
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName mysite.local
     Redirect permanent / https://mysite.local/
</VirtualHost>
```

### php -i

Opcache is enabled in the PHP container.

Some sections removed for brevity.

```
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.1.33

System => Linux 91e73afc9480 5.10.47-linuxkit #1 SMP Sat Jul 3 21:51:47 UTC 2021 x86_64
Build Date => Nov 22 2019 18:32:56
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d' '--enable-option-checking=fatal' '--with-mhash' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-sqlite=/usr' '--with-sqlite3=/usr' '--with-curl' '--with-libedit' '--with-openssl' '--with-zlib' '--with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--enable-fpm' '--with-fpm-user=www-data' '--with-fpm-group=www-data' '--disable-cgi' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu'
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pcov.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini

PHP API => 20160303
PHP Extension => 20160303
Zend Extension => 320160303
Zend Extension Build => API320160303,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20160303,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => enabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.33, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

apcu

APCu Support => Enabled
Version => 5.1.21
APCu Debugging => Disabled
MMAP Support => Enabled
MMAP File Mask =>
Serialization Support => php
Build Date => Nov  4 2021 16:03:09

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.enable_cli => On => On
apc.enabled => On => On
apc.entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.mmap_file_mask => no value => no value
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.serializer => php => php
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 32M => 32M
apc.slam_defense => Off => Off
apc.smart => 0 => 0
apc.ttl => 0 => 0
apc.use_request_time => Off => Off

Core

PHP Version => 7.1.33

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => UTF-8 => UTF-8
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
display_startup_errors => On => On
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 32767 => 32767
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303 => /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
file_uploads => On => On
hard_timeout => 2 => 2
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .:/usr/local/lib/php => .:/usr/local/lib/php
input_encoding => no value => no value
internal_encoding => no value => no value
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => Off => Off
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 4G => 4G
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_encoding => no value => no value
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 8M => 8M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 4096K => 4096K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => GP => GP
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path =>  -t -i  =>  -t -i
serialize_precision => -1 => -1
short_open_tag => Off => Off
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sql.safe_mode => Off => Off
sys_temp_dir => no value => no value
track_errors => Off => Off
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.assertions => 1 => 1
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value
zend.signal_check => Off => Off

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.64.0
Age => 4
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => Yes
SPNEGO => Yes
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
TLS-SRP => Yes
HTTP2 => Yes
GSSAPI => Yes
KERBEROS5 => Yes
UNIX_SOCKETS => Yes
PSL => Yes
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.1.1d
ZLib Version => 1.2.11
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.8.0

mysqlnd

mysqlnd => enabled
Version => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
Compression => supported
core SSL => supported
extended SSL => supported
Command buffer size => 4096
Read buffer size => 32768
Read timeout => 31536000
Collecting statistics => Yes
Collecting memory statistics => Yes
Tracing => n/a
Loaded plugins => mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password,auth_plugin_sha256_password
API Extensions => pdo_mysql

mysqlnd statistics =>
bytes_sent => 0
bytes_received => 0
packets_sent => 0
packets_received => 0
protocol_overhead_in => 0
protocol_overhead_out => 0
bytes_received_ok_packet => 0
bytes_received_eof_packet => 0
bytes_received_rset_header_packet => 0
bytes_received_rset_field_meta_packet => 0
bytes_received_rset_row_packet => 0
bytes_received_prepare_response_packet => 0
bytes_received_change_user_packet => 0
packets_sent_command => 0
packets_received_ok => 0
packets_received_eof => 0
packets_received_rset_header => 0
packets_received_rset_field_meta => 0
packets_received_rset_row => 0
packets_received_prepare_response => 0
packets_received_change_user => 0
result_set_queries => 0
non_result_set_queries => 0
no_index_used => 0
bad_index_used => 0
slow_queries => 0
buffered_sets => 0
unbuffered_sets => 0
ps_buffered_sets => 0
ps_unbuffered_sets => 0
flushed_normal_sets => 0
flushed_ps_sets => 0
ps_prepared_never_executed => 0
ps_prepared_once_executed => 0
rows_fetched_from_server_normal => 0
rows_fetched_from_server_ps => 0
rows_buffered_from_client_normal => 0
rows_buffered_from_client_ps => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_buffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_unbuffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_buffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_unbuffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_cursor => 0
rows_affected_normal => 0
rows_affected_ps => 0
rows_skipped_normal => 0
rows_skipped_ps => 0
copy_on_write_saved => 0
copy_on_write_performed => 0
command_buffer_too_small => 0
connect_success => 0
connect_failure => 0
connection_reused => 0
reconnect => 0
pconnect_success => 0
active_connections => 0
active_persistent_connections => 0
explicit_close => 0
implicit_close => 0
disconnect_close => 0
in_middle_of_command_close => 0
explicit_free_result => 0
implicit_free_result => 0
explicit_stmt_close => 0
implicit_stmt_close => 0
mem_emalloc_count => 0
mem_emalloc_amount => 0
mem_ecalloc_count => 0
mem_ecalloc_amount => 0
mem_erealloc_count => 0
mem_erealloc_amount => 0
mem_efree_count => 0
mem_efree_amount => 0
mem_malloc_count => 0
mem_malloc_amount => 0
mem_calloc_count => 0
mem_calloc_amount => 0
mem_realloc_count => 0
mem_realloc_amount => 0
mem_free_count => 0
mem_free_amount => 0
mem_estrndup_count => 0
mem_strndup_count => 0
mem_estrdup_count => 0
mem_strdup_count => 0
mem_edupl_count => 0
mem_dupl_count => 0
proto_text_fetched_null => 0
proto_text_fetched_bit => 0
proto_text_fetched_tinyint => 0
proto_text_fetched_short => 0
proto_text_fetched_int24 => 0
proto_text_fetched_int => 0
proto_text_fetched_bigint => 0
proto_text_fetched_decimal => 0
proto_text_fetched_float => 0
proto_text_fetched_double => 0
proto_text_fetched_date => 0
proto_text_fetched_year => 0
proto_text_fetched_time => 0
proto_text_fetched_datetime => 0
proto_text_fetched_timestamp => 0
proto_text_fetched_string => 0
proto_text_fetched_blob => 0
proto_text_fetched_enum => 0
proto_text_fetched_set => 0
proto_text_fetched_geometry => 0
proto_text_fetched_other => 0
proto_binary_fetched_null => 0
proto_binary_fetched_bit => 0
proto_binary_fetched_tinyint => 0
proto_binary_fetched_short => 0
proto_binary_fetched_int24 => 0
proto_binary_fetched_int => 0
proto_binary_fetched_bigint => 0
proto_binary_fetched_decimal => 0
proto_binary_fetched_float => 0
proto_binary_fetched_double => 0
proto_binary_fetched_date => 0
proto_binary_fetched_year => 0
proto_binary_fetched_time => 0
proto_binary_fetched_datetime => 0
proto_binary_fetched_timestamp => 0
proto_binary_fetched_string => 0
proto_binary_fetched_json => 0
proto_binary_fetched_blob => 0
proto_binary_fetched_enum => 0
proto_binary_fetched_set => 0
proto_binary_fetched_geometry => 0
proto_binary_fetched_other => 0
init_command_executed_count => 0
init_command_failed_count => 0
com_quit => 0
com_init_db => 0
com_query => 0
com_field_list => 0
com_create_db => 0
com_drop_db => 0
com_refresh => 0
com_shutdown => 0
com_statistics => 0
com_process_info => 0
com_connect => 0
com_process_kill => 0
com_debug => 0
com_ping => 0
com_time => 0
com_delayed_insert => 0
com_change_user => 0
com_binlog_dump => 0
com_table_dump => 0
com_connect_out => 0
com_register_slave => 0
com_stmt_prepare => 0
com_stmt_execute => 0
com_stmt_send_long_data => 0
com_stmt_close => 0
com_stmt_reset => 0
com_stmt_set_option => 0
com_stmt_fetch => 0
com_deamon => 0
bytes_received_real_data_normal => 0
bytes_received_real_data_ps => 0

openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value

pcov

PCOV support => Enabled
PCOV version => 1.0.9
pcov.directory => /home/wwwroot/mysite/src
pcov.exclude => none
pcov.initial.memory => 65336 bytes
pcov.initial.files => 64

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.38 2015-11-23
PCRE JIT Support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.jit => 1 => 1
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite, mysql

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket => no value => no value

pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
SQLite Library => 3.27.2


session

Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user
Registered serializer handlers => php_serialize php php_binary

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => Off => Off
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_secure => Off => Off
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 1 => 1
session.lazy_write => On => On
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => no value => no value
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.sid_bits_per_character => 5 => 5
session.sid_length => 26 => 26
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => On => On
session.use_only_cookies => On => On
session.use_strict_mode => Off => Off
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0

SimpleXML

Simplexml support => enabled
Revision => $Id: ae067cdcddf424d6e762603905b98798bc924a00 $
Schema support => enabled

standard

Dynamic Library Support => enabled
Path to sendmail =>  -t -i

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
assert.active => 1 => 1
assert.bail => 0 => 0
assert.callback => no value => no value
assert.exception => 0 => 0
assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0
assert.warning => 1 => 1
auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0
default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
from => no value => no value
session.trans_sid_hosts => no value => no value
session.trans_sid_tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form= => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=
url_rewriter.hosts => no value => no value
url_rewriter.tags => form= => form=
user_agent => no value => no value

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support => enabled

xml

XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
libxml2 Version => 2.9.4

xmlreader

XMLReader => enabled

xmlwriter

XMLWriter => enabled

Zend OPcache

Opcode Caching => Disabled
Optimization => Disabled
SHM Cache => Enabled
File Cache => Disabled
Startup Failed => Opcode Caching is disabled for CLI

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
opcache.blacklist_filename => no value => no value
opcache.consistency_checks => 0 => 0
opcache.dups_fix => Off => Off
opcache.enable => On => On
opcache.enable_cli => Off => Off
opcache.enable_file_override => Off => Off
opcache.error_log => no value => no value
opcache.fast_shutdown => 1 => 1
opcache.file_cache => no value => no value
opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks => 1 => 1
opcache.file_cache_only => 0 => 0
opcache.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
opcache.force_restart_timeout => 180 => 180
opcache.huge_code_pages => Off => Off
opcache.inherited_hack => On => On
opcache.interned_strings_buffer => 128 => 128
opcache.lockfile_path => /tmp => /tmp
opcache.log_verbosity_level => 1 => 1
opcache.max_accelerated_files => 100000 => 100000
opcache.max_file_size => 0 => 0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage => 10 => 10
opcache.memory_consumption => 2048 => 2048
opcache.opt_debug_level => 0 => 0
opcache.optimization_level => 0x7FFFBFFF => 0x7FFFBFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model => no value => no value
opcache.protect_memory => 0 => 0
opcache.restrict_api => no value => no value
opcache.revalidate_freq => 0 => 0
opcache.revalidate_path => Off => Off
opcache.save_comments => 1 => 1
opcache.use_cwd => On => On
opcache.validate_permission => Off => Off
opcache.validate_root => Off => Off
opcache.validate_timestamps => On => On

zip

Zip => enabled
Zip version => 1.13.5
Libzip version => 1.1.2

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.11
Linked Version => 1.2.11

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Additional Modules

Module Name

Environment

Variable => Value
HOSTNAME => 91e73afc9480
PHP_VERSION => 7.1.33
PHP_MD5 =>
SYMFONY_ENV => dev
PHP_INI_DIR => /usr/local/etc/php
GPG_KEYS => A917B1ECDA84AEC2B568FED6F50ABC807BD5DCD0 528995BFEDFBA7191D46839EF9BA0ADA31CBD89E 1729F83938DA44E27BA0F4D3DBDB397470D12172
PHP_LDFLAGS => -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=both -pie
PWD => /home/wwwroot/mysite
HOME => /root
PHP_SHA256 => bd7c0a9bd5433289ee01fd440af3715309faf583f75832b64fe169c100d52968
PHPIZE_DEPS => autoconf         dpkg-dev        file        g++         gcc         libc-dev        make        pkg-config      re2c
TERM => xterm
PHP_URL => https://www.php.net/get/php-7.1.33.tar.xz/from/this/mirror
PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS => --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --disable-cgi
SHLVL => 1
PHP_CFLAGS => -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
PATH => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PHP_ASC_URL => https://www.php.net/get/php-7.1.33.tar.xz.asc/from/this/mirror
PHP_CPPFLAGS => -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
_ => /usr/local/bin/php

PHP Variables

Variable => Value
$_SERVER['HOSTNAME'] => 91e73afc9480
$_SERVER['PHP_VERSION'] => 7.1.33
$_SERVER['PHP_MD5'] =>
$_SERVER['SYMFONY_ENV'] => dev
$_SERVER['PHP_INI_DIR'] => /usr/local/etc/php
$_SERVER['GPG_KEYS'] => A917B1ECDA84AEC2B568FED6F50ABC807BD5DCD0 528995BFEDFBA7191D46839EF9BA0ADA31CBD89E 1729F83938DA44E27BA0F4D3DBDB397470D12172
$_SERVER['PHP_LDFLAGS'] => -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=both -pie
$_SERVER['PWD'] => /home/wwwroot/mysite
$_SERVER['HOME'] => /root
$_SERVER['PHP_SHA256'] => bd7c0a9bd5433289ee01fd440af3715309faf583f75832b64fe169c100d52968
$_SERVER['PHPIZE_DEPS'] => autoconf         dpkg-dev        file        g++         gcc         libc-dev        make        pkg-config      re2c
$_SERVER['TERM'] => xterm
$_SERVER['PHP_URL'] => https://www.php.net/get/php-7.1.33.tar.xz/from/this/mirror
$_SERVER['PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS'] => --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --disable-cgi
$_SERVER['SHLVL'] => 1
$_SERVER['PHP_CFLAGS'] => -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
$_SERVER['PATH'] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
$_SERVER['PHP_ASC_URL'] => https://www.php.net/get/php-7.1.33.tar.xz.asc/from/this/mirror
$_SERVER['PHP_CPPFLAGS'] => -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
$_SERVER['_'] => /usr/local/bin/php
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] =>
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] =>
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] =>
$_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'] =>
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] =>
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] => 1636129412.782
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] => 1636129412
$_SERVER['argv'] => Array
(
)

$_SERVER['argc'] => 0

PHP License
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the PHP License as published by the PHP Group
and included in the distribution in the file:  LICENSE

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any
questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.
```

Comment: I don't know what the situation is like nowadays, but in the past I've heard many people complain that Docker is very slow on Mac OS because of file syncing, to the point that [applications exists](http://docker-sync.io/) to mitigate that.

Comment: This is also the subject of [Docker in MacOs is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55951014/docker-in-macos-is-very-slow); bind-mounting your entire application source is in fact not fast on MacOS, and I'm not aware of this having changed.

Answer (score 1):

Workarounds are to either use an sftp server and sync files with editor plugin on change or more easier method but less efficient to mount `var` folder with named volume.

Also in Apache only mount `public` directory of your project because all the php will run on php container.

```
volumes:
    app-var:
services:
   apache:
        volumes:
            - ./mysite/public:/home/wwwroot/mysite:delegated

    php:
        build: ./php
        container_name: mysite
        volumes:
            - ./mysite:/home/wwwroot/mysite:delegated
            - ./mysite/var:app-var
```