# Running command in docker container is 5x slower

Tags: docker

When running this command, I get a total build time of (on average) 70s.

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/app:/srv -w /srv --rm -it node:16 npm run build
```

When running the command directly, locally (`npm run build`) it takes on average 14s.

Is there a reason the command takes so much longer to run in a docker container?

```
System details:
macOS 12.5
docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
```

```
Resources given to docker: 
CPUs - 8
Memory - 8gb
Swap - 2gb
```

Comment: Is it the same problem as [Docker in MacOs is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55951014/docker-in-macos-is-very-slow)?  If you remove the `docker run -v` option and `RUN npm build` in a custom Dockerfile, is it faster?

Comment: @DavidMaze, ah yes it does look like that! I'll close this