# Docker is too slow to run the application on the MacBook Pro (M1) local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

Recently we have moved the rails application to docker for development. I am using **MacBook Pro (M1, 2020), OS Version: 12.0.1**. Now the application works, but that is extremely slow on local machine, is there anything we can do here to improve the performance, or are we doing something incorrectly?

**Rails Version**

```
rails (5.2.8.1)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.5.9

ENV INSTALL_PATH /opt/app
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
#   curl \
#   chromium \
  build-essential \
  libpq-dev \
  curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && \
  apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN gem install bundler -v 2.3.26
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
RUN bundle install

WORKDIR /opt/app/core-project

VOLUME ["$INSTALL_PATH/public"]

# For Rails
EXPOSE 4000
```

**config/database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  url: postgresql://postgres@host.docker.internal:5432/coredb?encoding=utf8&pool=5&timeout=5000
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2
  rails-server:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        USER_ID: "${USER_ID:-1000}"
        GROUP_ID: "${GROUP_ID:-1000}"
    command: ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./
        target: /opt/app/core-project
    ports:
      - '4000:3000'
    env_file:
      - .env

  sidekiq:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        USER_ID: "${USER_ID:-1000}"
        GROUP_ID: "${GROUP_ID:-1000}"
    command: ["bundle", "exec", "sidekiq"]
    depends_on:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./
        target: /opt/app/core-project
    env_file:
      - .env
```

**application.rb**

```
# Added to resolve the segmentation issue when running the application in Docker.
config.assets.configure do |env|
  env.export_concurrent = false
end
```

Comment: That sounds like you're running into [Docker in MacOs is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55951014/docker-in-macos-is-very-slow).  For a development environment, I might `brew install rbenv` to get a local Ruby, and skip Docker; for pre-deployment testing, delete the `volumes:` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is not a good solution to dev.
use RVM to avoid ruby version mismatching .

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io  | bash
```

and after you source the right things in the post install logs
you can specify the version you want to have :

```
rvm install x.X.X
```

Where x.X.X is the ruby version you want
clone or copy pour project , and run bundle install .
google your error of installs (if you have some)
IT should be now BLAZIN'FAST